# I want to plot graph in excel linking two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to plot graph but it is not inverting the axis.

[image]

I want x axis in y and y in X.  If I try, it becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: Select an XY chart (scatter chart).  Verify that the series are defined as columns rather than rows.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the chart & select "Select Data" Click on your data series & then click the Edit button. In the resulting window select "A1" for the series name (or type in "Precipitation"), select the temperatures (B2:B21) for the X values and the Precipitation values (A2:A21) for the Y values.